# UI spit view capability

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

There is something id really like to probably try in an app but would like to know if it can be done.

With a UI Splitview, we know if we change the left view...the right view changes
so example we have a left view containing cat names. so each time we change the cat name in the left view controller we see an image of the cat in the right. but I was wondering if it was possible that some how the name of the cat gets passed in n a previous screen. and when we change the left controller we get different characteristics of that particular cat
like eye colour, colour etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left view typically has a navigation controller, which means you can drill down through various levels of information and choices until you get to the one that needs to use the right side for extra detail.

Comment: i know this but to use my example of the "cat name" again Lets say i have two kittens(fluffy and tuffy)
Im trying for when i select one cat (say fluffy) that the UIplitvew comes up and i can drill thru the left for information about fluffy Ie colour, size etc etc and its eye colour will be shown in the right side.

Comment: Why not make the original selection in the master part of the split view to begin the drill down?  UISplitViewController was intended to be the root of any interface it's used in.  ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html )  Fighting against that is usually painful.

Comment: i read what you say but...can't i do it like how it is done on the ipad. Like when i click the settings button... the screen u get so cant  i have like two of those buttons? (i for fluffy and one for tuffy)?

Comment: if i had to have an orginal selector of 'cat names' in the master/right part of the uisplitvew with an empty left side. (say fluffy and tuffy again) if i touch fluffy, can i load a new ui that has "image , colour " on the left and when i touch it i see a picture of the cat on the right?